# How to send datapicker value from API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created simple react Datepicker application. I get date from API stored useState()  function `const [datebirth, setDateBirth] = useState('');` after I changed date will send request another API. I want to update API. I will provide my code.

my handleChangeInput:

```
const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setDatas((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

Datepicker Stored Date useState:

`const [datebirth, setDateBirth] = useState('');`

Get Date From API this format `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [decryptedAccessToken]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/allcontactsbyID/" + id,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },
        }
      );
      const data = response.data[0].contact_details;
       
      var d_o_b=response.data[0].contact_details.birthdate;
      console.log(dataLength); 
      setDatas(data);
      const dob = parse(d_o_b, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date());
      const dobresult = format(dob, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
      setDateBirth(dobresult)
      setTimeout(() => {
        $("#quotes").DataTable();
        $("#history").DataTable();
      }, 10);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Update API:

```
  const handleSaveEdit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();  
        
        const responseData={
          "saluation":datas.saluation,
          "first_name":datas.first_name,
          "last_name":datas.last_name, 
          "birthdate":datebirth,
          "title":datas.title,
          "account_name":datas.account_name,
          "reports_to":datas.reports_to,
          "contact_email":datas.contact_email,
          "contact_mobile":datas.contact_mobile,
          "contact_owner":datas.contact_owner,
          "department":datas.department,
          "lead_source":datas.lead_source,
          "mail_street":datas.mail_street,
          "mail_postal_code":datas.mail_postal_code,
          "mail_city":datas.mail_city,
          "mail_state":datas.mail_state,
          "mail_country":datas.mail_country
          
        };
        
        fetch(`https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/contact/update/${id}`, {  
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(responseData),
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}`,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
             
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((updatedData) => {
            console.log(updatedData) 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData))
            if(updatedData.msg==='contact updated successfully'){
             
              // fetchData();
          }
           
            setData(updatedData);
            setIsEditMode(false);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      };
```

My form:

```
<>
          
            <p className='edit-btn'>
     <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSaveEdit}>Save</button>
     <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleCancelEdit}>Cancel</button>
     
     
     </p>
     <Row className="mb-3">
     
     <div className='col-md-12'>
     <h4 className='heading'>Contact Information</h4>
     </div>
     
     <Form.Group
     as={Col}
     md="6"
     id='' 
     >
     <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingSelect" className='dropDown' label="Salutation">
     <Form.Select aria-label="Floating label select example"
     name="saluation" 
     placeholder="Salutation"
     defaultValue={datas.saluation || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}
     >
     <option value='' disabled>--None--</option>
     <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
     <option value="Ms">Ms</option> 
     <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option> 
     <option value="Dr">Dr</option> 
     <option value="Prof">Prof</option> 
     </Form.Select> 
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     <Form.Group
     as={Col}
     md="6"
     
     >
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="First Name"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     <Form.Control
     type="text"
     placeholder="First Name"
     name="first_name"
     defaultValue={datas.contact_full_name || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/> 
     </FloatingLabel>
     
     </Form.Group>
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Last Name"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Last Name" 
     name="last_name"
     defaultValue={datas.last_name || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Birth Date"
     className="mb-3 datepick"
     
     
     >
     <DatePicker
     selected={startDate1}
     onChange={(date) => setStartDate1(date)}
     customInput={<CustomInput />}
     dayClassName={() => "example-datepicker-day-class"}
     popperClassName="example-datepicker-class"
     todayButton="TODAY"
     dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'
     
     placeholderText='Birth Date'
     />
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     
     <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingSelect" 
     className='dropDown' label="Account name">
     <Form.Select aria-label="Floating label select example"
     name="account_name"
     id='account_name' 
     placeholder="Account name" 
     defaultValue={datas.account_name || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}
     
     > 
     <option value='' >Select</option>
     {
     accountNames.map((x)=>{
     return(
     <option value={x.account_name}>{x.account_name}</option>
     )
     })
     }
     </Form.Select> 
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group> 
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Reports to"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Reports to" 
     name="reports_to"
     defaultValue={datas.reports_to || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Contact Owner"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Contact Owner" 
     name="contact_owner"
     defaultValue={datas.contact_owner || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Department"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Department" 
     name="department"
     defaultValue={datas.department || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     
     <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingSelect" 
     className='dropDown' label="Lead Source">
     <Form.Select aria-label="Floating label select example"
     name="lead_source"
     id='account_name' 
     placeholder="Account name" 
     defaultValue={datas.lead_source || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}
     > 
     <option value="">--None--</option>
     <option value="Advertisement">Advertisement</option>
     <option value="Customer Event">Customer Event</option>
     <option value="Employee Referral">Employee Referral</option>
     <option value="Google AdWords">Google AdWords</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
     <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
     <option value="Purchased List">Purchased List</option>
     <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
     <option value="Webinar">Webinar</option>
     <option value="Website">Website</option>
     <option value="Rajgopalan">Rajgopalan</option>
     <option value="Olivia">Olivia</option>
     
     </Form.Select>
     
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group> 
     
     
     
     </Row>
     <Row>
     <div className='col-md-12'>
     <h4 className='heading'>Contact Information</h4>
     </div>
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" id='contact-title'>
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Title"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control
     type="text" 
     placeholder="Title" 
     name="title"
     defaultValue={datas.title || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Contact Email"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Contact Email" 
     name="contact_email"
     defaultValue={datas.contact_email || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Contact Mobile"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Contact Mobile" 
     name="contact_mobile"
     defaultValue={datas.contact_mobile || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     </Row>
     
     <Row>
     <div className='col-md-12'>
     <h4 className='heading'>Address Information</h4>
     </div>
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Mail Street"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Mail Street" 
     name="mail_street"
     defaultValue={datas.mail_street || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Mail postal code"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Mail postal code" 
     name="mail_postal_code"
     defaultValue={datas.mail_postal_code || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Mail city"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Mail city" 
     name="mail_city"
     defaultValue={datas.mail_city || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Mail state"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Mail state" 
     name="mail_state"
     defaultValue={datas.mail_state || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
     <FloatingLabel
     controlId="floatingInput"
     label="Mail country"
     className="mb-3"
     >
     
     <Form.Control type="text" 
     placeholder="Mail country" 
     name="mail_country"
     defaultValue={datas.mail_country || ""}
     onChange={handleChangeInput}/>
     </FloatingLabel>
     </Form.Group>
     
     </Row>
     <p className='edit-btn'>
     <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSaveEdit}>Save</button>
     <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleCancelEdit}>Cancel</button>
     
     
     </p> </>
```

Comment: What is the actual issue you are facing here ?.

Comment: I get date from API, again want send another update API, I want update date.

Comment: You only need to give a **minimal** reproducible example. It's worth trimming down to something more lean.  Surely we don't need 330+ lines of jsx.

Comment: can you give example code, react datepicker one input field example please

Comment: @SivaMCA there are so many libraries available for this, you could first search and implement it